# Release mechanism for car drop session

Tags: car, foley, effect, impacts

Hello, we are doing a car drop session and everything else has been already planned apart from one last thing. I haven´t been able to find any reasonable system for the release mechanism that connects the car to the crane. I´ve bee looking for products such as Elebia e5 crane hook system and Henriksen HMKST 8.0, MOB-Hook, WLL 8.0 T Art No.: HH000028, with the conclusion that neither of these are optimal for such task. I´ve heard that magnetic "hooks" and suction devices could also be used to lift cars to roughly about 30 meters high. Frankly this stuff goes bit beyond my set of skills and knowledge so any ideas concerning the subject is greatly appreciated. It would also be preferable if we could rent the system for a day or two instead of buying. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a pretty great question/answer.

Answer (score 3):

When I dropped cars, we used this massive forklift thing:

https://plus.google.com/photos/112773450273987656053/albums/5575619157179451041/5575619181206793730

The great thing about the forklift vs cranes, is that it is very quick, you don't have to rig up quick release systems, and there is no reset time.  The downside is that your operator has to shut the engine of the forklift off the second he releases the car.  This is the method that John Fasal uses and he's done more car drops than anyone will ever do, so he's got it all figured out.

More photos from my drop session here:

https://plus.google.com/photos/112773450273987656053/albums/5575619157179451041

Comment: Hmm.. That seems to work quite well, the only downside is that we wanted to get the cars up to 30 meter high. How much of kinetic force can you get with such height, do the drops sound violent enough?

Comment: @Chuck Russom how many cars did you use on this session?

Comment: @ Ville Sora Wow, 30 meters is pretty high!  I think we got ours up to 40 feet, which is 12 meters or so.  They are pretty damn violent sounding, I can't imagine needing anything more.

Comment: @RedSonic01 I think we did 12 cars, with multiple drops each, over 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for those who ever might need the similar kind of mechanism, we used 70 ton crane to pull cars up to 20 meters and a Henriksen hook and a rope worked just fine. I`m sure there are similar companies that build these kinds of maritime hooks all over the world and I suggest you try to either lend them or rent them as they seem to be extremely costly.

Its also worth mentioning that drops beyond 10 meters seem to have less texture and more of a less interesting "bang" due to the force of impact. Its also better to drop them to another car rather tahn pavement or metal plates, it also gives more detail to the impacts.